# CheckedTextView in ListView doesn't get toggled using AVD SDK 2.2

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am debugging my application in different APIs using AVD. Using 4.2.1 ( or API 16/17 ) target platform, everything works smoothly. But when I use API 8, one of checkboxed doesn't get toggled. Is it or bug or what? My code is below:

listview_item_checkbox.xml

```
<CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:paddingTop="7dp"
    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
     />
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    CheckedTextView checkBox = (CheckedTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    final int finalPosition = position;
    if (checkBox != null) {

        checkBox.toggle();
```